# FluentNHibernate Auto Mappings and ISet in .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

How to set up auto mapping to map `System.Collections.Generics.ISet<T>` correctly?

I tried implementing `IHasManyConvention`, but in intellisense it seems that `IOneToManyCollectionInstance` does not have anything for that(?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not up to Fluent NHibernate, because NHibernate just doesn't have any built-in implementation for `System.Collections.Generics.ISet<T>`.

If you really want to use .NET's ISet instead of Iesi.Collections, for now you'll have to write it yourself. Use [PersistentGenericSet](https://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Collection/Generic/PersistentGenericSet.cs) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only generic you can automap right out of the box (i.e. without Conventions, Overrides, or Mapping Classes) is IList.

I've seen a lot of people ask how to map IDictionary, and believe it is possible, but have not needed to do this myself.

But maybe if you do some searching on mapping IDictionaries, you'll learn enough to map an ISet.  And if you succeed, please post the code here as an answer to your question!