# NHibernate and .net-4.0 new ISet<T> collections

Tags: nhibernate, collections, .net-4.0

I there any new use of the new .net 4 ISet collections with NHibernate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702077/fluentnhibernate-auto-mappings-and-iset-in-net-4-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not yet. It's planned for future releases.